# Spinner Dropdown instead of Pop up with an overlay?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to have my spinner drop down just like a web form. I don't want the options to pop up in a modal style window. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in SDK as far as I know, so I guess you will have to write your own Spinner to get this functionality. It would be nice though :)

Comment: Boo. You would think something like that would be included....the modal style overlay is annoying for every option..

Answer (score 13):

The feature you're looking for is the spinnerMode attribute which has "popup" and "dropdown" modes, which you should set to "dropdown" in order to get what you want. Just add

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

to the  declaration in your layout XML.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could just use MODE_DROPDOWN with the spinner.

Comment: Could you tell where to put that flag?